# How to add 2 display form in one?

Tags: list, javascript, custom-list, display-form, related-list

Recently I was worked with **Related list** and it solved lots of problem from my users in SharePoint 2013. I am wonder if I can add 2 Lists **Display form** in one. This is one of my users idea's and she meant not 2 but about 4 Display form in one. Her problem is the long Form and fields and this idea came up when she was looking to **wrap the Display or New Form**.
Any Idea or experience is appreciable.

Comment: It is possible with custom form.

Comment: To be more precise, you need to display New/Display/Edit for of four list in a single page? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Do you want to use the functionality of expand/collapse the default form in modal dialog?

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear, well yes as @NagarajanMuthukumar said I am looking for displaying  New/Display/Edit for of four list in a single page.